# Vector Row product vs Matrix products, Vastly different calculation speeds

Tags: vectorization, octave, matrix-multiplication

Can anybody explain the vastly different speeds I obtain with a row * vector vectorized calculation vs a matrix .* matrix calculation? I obtain 
0.000959158 seconds for row*vector
and 0 seconds for matrix.*matrix
The code I attached makes exactly the same calculation for FV and FM and then plots the identical result just to show that the results are identical. I was expecting some difference but not 0.00009 vs nothing.

```
 %Plots the Fair Skill Score for a binary event 
    % Initialization %
    clear ; close all; clc
    %input parameters
    m = 2; %number of mutually exclusive events
    printf('Running Fair Skill Score ... ');
    f = linspace(0,1,21); %20 real frequencies of event
    p = linspace(0,1,26); %25 probabilities attributed by forecaster

tic
FV = log(m) + f' * log(p) + (1-f') * log(1-p);%fair score formula, calculated as matrix 
toc
[X,Y]= meshgrid(f,p); %set mesh grid for 3D surface plot

tic
FM = log(m) + X .* log(Y) + (1-X) .* log(1-Y);
toc

subplot(1,2,1)
surf(X,Y,FV');%FV is transposed because X and Y are vectors
title (['Fair Skill']);
xlabel(['frequency']);
ylabel("probability forecast");
zlabel("score");
colorbar
subplot(1,2,2)
surf(X,Y,FM)
```

Comment: Singular `tic`/`toc` calls is an unreliable timing method, use [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) instead. `0.0009` is essentially 0 seconds anyway, this is in no way "vastly" different performance.

Comment: Any time you measure that is less than a hundredth of a second is meaningless, and any time less than a tenth of a second or so is unreliable. A lot of things are going on in your computer that can delay execution of your program. Plus, you're timing the calls to `log`, which are way more expensive than multiplications.

Comment: `[X,Y] = meshgrid... log(1-Y);` ia a bad idea and very expensive since you calulate `log` for the same value in rows of Y again and again.... And as Cris Luengo already said: your benchmark setup isn't suited to tests this. Try to increase the number of points for f and p until you get runtimes of >1s